# Unable to edit IntelliJ keymap settings, "nothing to show"

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm unable to edit my IntelliJ keymap for some reason. The box which I assume should be showing possible actions and linked keyboard shortcuts is empty. Does anyone know a fix?

[image: The problem]

Comment: Does it help if you [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins and restart the IDE?

Comment: Try using the latest IDE version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I tried removing some themes (had a few so not sure which was the culprit then reset the IDE. It worked!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).